# relation between two classes (german code)

Tags: java

I want to make an array with which I can create some instances of the class `Schiff` (Ship) by using the class `Flotte` (Armada). Somehow it does not work. Which method is more useful? `addShiff` or `addSchiff2`?

```
public class Schiff
{
private String material;
private int kanonen;
private int ursprungsMäste;
private int mästeStehenNoch;

public Schiff (String material, int kanonen, int mäste)
{
    this.material = material;
    this.kanonen = kanonen;
    ursprungsMäste = mäste;
    mästeStehenNoch = mäste;
}

public String gibMaterial()
{
    return material;
}

public void mastGetroffen(int wieVieleTreffer)
{
    mästeStehenNoch = mästeStehenNoch - wieVieleTreffer;
}


public void wieVieleMäste ()
{
    System.out.println("Es stehen noch " + mästeStehenNoch + " Mäste!");
}
}
```

+++++++

```
public class Flotte
{
private Schiff [] flottenArray;

public Flotte ()
{
    flottenArray = new Schiff [100];
}

public void addSchiff (String material, int kanonen, int ursprungsMäste)
{
    for (int zahl = 0; zahl<flottenArray.length; zahl++)
    {
        if (flottenArray[zahl] == null)
        {
            flottenArray[zahl] = new Schiff (material, kanonen, ursprungsMäste);
        }
    }
}

    public void addSchiff2 (Schiff neuesSchiff)
{
    for (int zahl = 0; zahl<flottenArray.length; zahl++)
    {
        if (flottenArray[zahl] == null)
        {
            flottenArray[zahl] = neuesSchiff;
        }
    }
}

public void gegnerischerFeuerAngriff ()
{
    for (Schiff schiff : flotte)
    {
        if (schiff.gibMaterial().equals("holz"))
        {
            flottenArray.remove(schiff);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please add a tag for programming language (Java ?).

Comment: This question belongs on code review.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly does not work?

Looks good to me.

My feeling is that you can drop the `addSchiff (String material, int kanonen, int ursprungsMäste)` method because:

*One*: It is just another way of writing `addSchiff2(new Schiff(material, kanonen, ursprungsMäste))` and this is also how it should be coded to avoid [repeating yourself](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself):

```
public void addSchiff (String material, int kanonen, int ursprungsMäste)
{
   addSchiff2(new Schiff(material, kanonen, ursprungsMäste))
}
```

*Two*: If you later decide to add fields to class `Schiff` you will have to change the interface of `Flotte` if you keep the method that constructs a `Schiff` instance from passed parameters. This is not the case if you just have a method that takes a `Schiff` instance. So getting rid of `addSchiff()` decreased inter-class coupling, which is gut.

Klar zur Halse!

Comment: Thanks for your input. So when I use addSchiff2, I add a Schiff created before but I can`t decide on the parameters, right? +++ The problem is that when I want to compile "Flotte", it says "cannot find symbol - variable flotte" but I don't understand why...!

Comment: @user3272780 - Yes. You decide on the parameters when you create Schiff, then you pass that Schiff to the Flotte. It is unwise to code Flotte so that it "needs to know" what kind of parameters a Schiff is given. For the problem: In "gegnerischerFeuerAngriff()" you use "flotte" but that does not exist - it is a "flottenArray"

Comment: Thanks. But still IT DOES NOT WORK as it says "cannot find symbol - method remove(Schiff)". I guess remove needs int as its parameter. But in my case I need Schiff...

Comment: @Lepard That is right. Because an old-schoold array is accessed by an integer index. The big problem is: If you have tho Schiff instances, how do you decide they are the same? You may need to give every Schiff a Schiffsname. [Then you implement equals() on Schiff](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/EffectiveJava/01.Equals-Part1/01.Equals1.html), replace the array by a [java.util.Set of Schiff](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) and THEN you can properly use `.remove()`